# How to connect two Route Arrays and dynamically add canActivate: [...] to one of them

Tags: angular, typescript

In the app.module file I have currently a Route Array which looks like this:

```
const ROUTES = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'component1',
    component: Component1Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'component2'
    component: Component2Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'signin-callback',
    component: SigninRedirectCallbackComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I want to split this array into two arrays `PROTECTED_ROUTES` and `UNPROTECTED_ROUTES`. In a function `getAllRoutes` for all routes in the `PROTECTED_ROUTES` array the parameter `canActivate: [AuthGuardService]` should be added. After that the two arrays are merged and returned.

Somehow like this:

```
const PROTECTED_ROUTES = [
  {
    path: 'component1',
    component: Component1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'component2'
    component: Component2Component
  }
];

const UNPROTECTED_ROUTES = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'signin-callback',
    component: SigninRedirectCallbackComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

function getAllRoutes() {
  // let protectedRoutes = PROTECTED_ROUTES;
  // protectedRoutes.forEach(r => 
  //   r.
  // somehow add canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  //   );

  protectedRoutes = protectedRoutes + UNPROTECTED_ROUTES //pseudo code
  return protectedRoutes;
}
```

Is it possible to add parameters to object array entries afterwards?
Can two object arrays be merged if they have different parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I could solve it like that:

```
const PROTECTED_ROUTES = [
  {
    path: 'component1',
    component: Component1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'component2'
    component: Component2Component
  }
];

const UNPROTECTED_ROUTES = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'signin-callback',
    component: SigninRedirectCallbackComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

function addGuard(routes: any[]): any[] {
  routes.forEach(entry => (entry.canActivate = [AuthGuardService]));
  return routes;
}
```

and in the imports:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([...addGuard(PROTECTED_ROUTES), ...UNPROTECTED_ROUTES], {
      // ...
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

create a path protected and unprotected.
make your paths the child of these two categories and then apply canActiavte on /protected so that it will be applicable for all its child paths. and /unprotected without canActivate will have those child which does not require canActivate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to angular routing. Will the paths stay the same with this approach?